# Django - no migrations folder after refactoring projects and apps names

Tags: python, django

I have refactored my app and project names, but after that Django doesn't create migrations folder in my app and doesn't actually apply my models migrations.

Even after migrations (with no warning nor error) I have no tables with my objects.

Does anybody know how to force django to do those migrations?

Comment: did you try creating 'migrations' folder in app?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't help

Comment: `migrations/__init__.py` file are considered to have migrations and your app name must be in installed apps in `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

There can multiple reasons behind it. Please check following if you are missing something.

- The app must have `migrations/__init__.py` folder. It automatically creates but if you did code refactoring. You can miss this.
- Check `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` it should have the same app name as in `admin.py`.